# Microsoft Bot Framework - Facebook Integration - Net Framework

Tags: c#, node.js, facebook, azure, botframework

I have a Chatbot Solution created using .Net Framework which is integrated with Facebook messenger using the following instructions from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Now they added a message saying: "Starting December 16, 2019, Workplace by Facebook is changing security model for custom integrations. Current integrations built with Microsoft Bot Framework need to be updated to use Bot Framework Adapter (available in JavaScript/Node.js) and deployed using a Web App on Azure. New Workplace bots that are developed using Microsoft Bot Framework should also use the JavaScript Facebook adapter."

They provided a solution for bots built-in using Node.js but there isn't a solution for .Net Framework bots.

Did someone get it resolved in any way?

Comment: I haven't seen any changes in facebook documentation regarding this change. Does this also affects normal Facebook messenger integration and not WorkPlace ?

Comment: You say you have a Messenger bot, so why are you worried about changes to Workplace? (Since there are more than two people in this thread, you will have to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply)

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answers. As you said it's related to "Workplace" and not to normal facebook messenger integration. I misunderstood since the "notice" is added immediately under "Connect a bot to Facebook Messenger". My bot still working today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note applies to Facebook for Workplace and not Facebook Messenger